# MongoConnectionTimeOut is not working using the MongoClientURI

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to connect MongoDB using MongoClientURI(URL) my URL is mongodb://userName:Password@host:PortNumber/DBName?connectTimeoutMS=10000 
when my MongoDB is Down i try to Post Request but it take default time 30 sec.
Can any one help me solve the problem

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you using a client driver or making a direct connection to Mongo? If you are using a client driver (e.g. Java, Node.js etc) then the driver may be applying a default on your behalf or ignoring the value you supplied for connectionTimeoutMS or it might be serving you up a connection from a pool rather than attempting to create a new connection each time.

Comment: MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(URL));
MongoDatabase mongodatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase(dbName);         MongoCollection<org.bson.Document> coll = mongodatabase.getCollection(collection);                                                              FindIterable<org.bson.Document> cursor1 =coll.find(searchQuery)     my code is like this and i am using driver is  "mongo-java-driver-3.2.2"            Please suggest how to put connection timeout for MongoDB.    Thanks in Advnce.

Comment: If you're using MongoClientURI, you can set custom timeout like this.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41803317/9498804

Answer (score 1):

You can set timeouts by using the Mongo Java client's `MongoClientOptions`. For example:

```
    MongoClientOptions clientOptions = MongoClientOptions.builder()
            .connectTimeout(...)
            .socketTimeout(...)
            .serverSelectionTimeout(...)
            .build();

    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(host, port), clientOptions);
```

Examining `mongoClient.getMongoClientOptions()` after the above line of code clearly shows that the created client is faithful to the supplied config values. By contrast, if you do not set these values via `MongoClientOptions` then `mongoClient.getMongoClientOptions()` shows that the default values have been chosen.

Based on your updated comments I *think* the situation you are trying to cater for is this:

> Creating a connection against a server instance which does not exists / is unavailable should fail sooner that the default of 30s.

If so then the configuration parameter you want to use is `serverSelectionTimeout`. The following invocation ...

```
    MongoClientOptions clientOptions = MongoClientOptions.builder()
            .serverSelectionTimeout(2000)
            .build();

    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(host, port), clientOptions);
```

... will cause this exception to be thrown:

> com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 2000 ms while waiting to connect.

Note: `serverSelectionTimeout` **is** available in the version of the MongoDB Java driver which you are using (3.2.2 according to the comment you posted on your question).

Comment: creds.add(MongoCredential.createCredential(username, dbName, password.toCharArray()));MongoClientOptions.Builder optionsBuilder = MongoClientOptions.builder();
   optionsBuilder.connectTimeout(Integer.parseInt(connectionTimeOut));
MongoClientOptions options = optionsBuilder.build();
   mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(hostname , Integer.parseInt(port)), creds, options);
mongodatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase(dbName);    ...Now my Mongo server is Down and i configure connectionTime=10000 but it is still taking 30s time(DefaultTime)

Comment: I have updated the answer in a bid to address your latest comment. If this does not work for you, could you please describe exactly what connection failure scenario(s) you are trying to cater for.

Comment: Thank  you very much for your response .ConnectionTimeOut working fine but i am trying to put socketTimeOut it is not working on the same code.optionsBuilder.socketTimeout(Integer.parseInt(socketTimeOut));        it is not taking that value .it is taking default value infinity .can you help me to put socketTimeOut .

Comment: Could you explain **why** you want to set socketTimeout? Perhaps you could explain exactly what you are trying to achieve then I may be able to suggest a solution.

Comment: some cases from MongoDB we are trying to fetching like more than 100 records due to network slow the reading time very slow .suppose  north bound system is expected the response and suppose my application receive ( 200 -300) per sec all 200 sec expect the response from my application and all threads  in waiting state.
 this there is a chance to down the application server  because of above scenario i need to put  the socket Timeout. can you explain how to solve this problem

Comment: Perhaps you should throttle traffic coming through your application server rather than letting it all stack up at the Mongo layer? I'm not very confident making that statement though since I don't think I fully understand your last comment. Anyway, I think my answer accurately describes how to set connectTimeout and serverSelectionTimeout on the Mongo client using the Mongo Java 3.2.2 driver.